# Soft delete issue with Hibernate and H2 in memory

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've decided to try soft delete mechanism that was described in [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-soft-delete-with-hibernate/). 
There is an AbstractEntity in my domain model with deleted indicator:

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class AbstractEntity {
@Column(name = "deleted_ind", nullable = false)
Boolean deleted = Boolean.FALSE
}
```

And there is a Job entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "job")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE job SET deleted_ind = true WHERE job_id = ?")
@Loader(namedQuery = "findJobById")
@NamedQuery(name = "findJobById", query =
    "SELECT j FROM Job j WHERE j.id = ? AND j.deleted = false")
@Where(clause = "deleted_ind = false")
class Job extends AbstractEntity {
@Id
@Column(name = "job_id", nullable = false)
String id
}
```

But when i'm trying to run my integration tests using h2 in-memory, exception occurs:

```
Hibernate: UPDATE job SET deleted_ind = true WHERE job_id = ?
2017-03-13 10:24:13,719 [main] INFO  o.h.e.j.b.i.AbstractBatchImpl - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements 
2017-03-13 10:24:13,720 [main] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 90008, SQLState: 90008 
2017-03-13 10:24:13,720 [main] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Invalid value "2" for parameter "parameterIndex" [90008-192] 
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not delete: [com.tolledo.myapp.Job#a]
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Invalid value "2" for parameter "parameterIndex" [90008-192]
```

Could you please assist with this issue?

UPDATE:
Simple Spring data JpaRepository is being used and in this particular test 'detete' method is being called.

FINAL UPDATE:
Oh, i just realized that i forgot to add 'version' to query. There is

```
@Version
@Column(name = "version", nullable = false)
Integer version
```

in my AbstractEntity, so final SQLDELETE looks like:

```
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE job SET deleted_ind = true WHERE job_id = ? and version = ?")
```

Comment: add the transactinoal method that causes this error

Comment: @MaciejKowalski done. I guess there is some issue with SQLDelete prepared statement, but can't figure out what exactly

Answer (score 0):

Change SQL this way

```
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE job SET deleted_ind = 1 WHERE job_id = ?")

@Where(clause = "deleted_ind = 0")
```

Comment: The same exception.